# React Native Deep Linking - Not navigating to url

Tags: javascript, objective-c, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

EDIT: I should note, we are using v4 of react-navigation

I am trying to hook up deep linking in my React Native app in IOS, and everything seems to be working except sending the following command line the app to opens...

`xcrun simctl openurl booted mydemoapp://Login`

however it's not navigating to `Login` when the app opens.

First my navigator is set up as follows:

```
const APP_URI_PREFIX = 'mydemoapp://';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Landing: LandingScreen,
    Login: LoginContainer,
    Registration: RegistrationContainer,
    ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordContainer,
    ResetPassword: ResetPasswordContainer,
    EmailVerification: EmailVerificationContainer
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  },
);

const MainNavigator = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Auth: AuthStack,
    App: AppStack,
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
  }
));

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <MainNavigator
    ref={ref}
    uriPrefix={APP_URI_PREFIX}
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState, action) => {
      const currentRouteName = getActiveRoute(currentState);
      const previousRouteName = getActiveRoute(prevState);

      if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
        ACPCore.trackState(currentRouteName.routeName, { "foo": currentState.params });
      }
    }}
  />
));
```

in my workspace settings I have Url Types for mydemoapp and the first url is for the FaceBookSdk

[image]

and last but not least I have the following in my AppDelegate...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  if ([RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  return NO;
}
```

Comment: did you find anything?
i'm also struggling with this